# Unix shell - how to filter out files by number of lines?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I am trying to extract all files with a line count greater than x using the following code.

```
for i in massive*;
do
 if [ wc -l $i | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > 50 ]; then
     mv $i subset_massive_subcluster_num_gt50/;
 fi; 
done
```

However I am getting the following error everytime it goes through the loop:

```
cut: ]: No such file or directory
-bash: [: missing `]'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Run your code through [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) and fix the obvious issues first.

Comment: I don't know what any of that means

Comment: shellcheck is a program that warns about many common shell scripting errors. It will complain about parsing errors on that snippet as your code is not exactly valid the way it is written (hence your error).

Comment: Specifically, you aren't actually running that `wc`/`cut` pipeline. Those are all literal words to the `test`/`[` command.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
for i in massive*;
do
 if [ wc -l $i | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > 50 ]; then
     mv $i subset_massive_subcluster_num_gt50/;
 fi; 
done
```

To this:

```
for i in massive*;
do
    if [ "$(wc -l "$i" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)" -gt 50 ]; then
        mv "$i" subset_massive_subcluster_num_gt50/;
    fi; 
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
for file in massive*
do
    [[ $(grep -c '' "$file") > 50 ]] && echo mv "$file" subset_massive_subcluster_num_gt50/
done
```

the `grep -c ''` is nicer (and safer) than `wc -l | cut`

The above is for "dry run". Remove the `echo` if satisfied.